# marquee: fetch text from txt file hosted on cloud drive

Tags: javascript, html, notifications, marquee

I'm searching for an easy way to update a simple marquee on an HTML5 web page (e.g. displaying "we're on vacation from...") not via hard coding on the page itself but via an external txt file to be read. The thing is the text file should be hosted on a common cloud drive like Google drive or OneDrive. I make the file publicly available and include the public link to the txt file in the website code. Then I should be able to adapt the txt file in the cloud drive and see my edits in the marquee on the page. 
Please support. Do you have other, better ideas? thx

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.setInterval(function(){
  ajaxCallFunction();  //calling every 5 seconds
}, 5000);

function ajaxCallFunction(){
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
     document.getElementById("textDisplay").innerHTML = xhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "YOUR TEXT DOCUMENT HERE", true);
  xhttp.setRequestHeader("Pragma","no-cache");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Cache-Control","no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Expires",0);
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("Last-Modified", new Date(0));
    xhttp.setRequestHeader("If-Modified-Since", new Date(0));
  xhttp.send();
}
</script>
<marquee id="textDisplay"></marquee>
</html>
```

This will use ajax to pull the contents of your text file from wherever you have stored it, just use the share link from the cloud service you are using. It will update the text every 5 seconds.

**EDIT**
Ok, I've taken a look at your plunker and run the code in a browser. The error being returned in the console seems to indicate that the page you are requesting info from is redirecting you:
[image: Redirect error]

I'm not sure where to go from here, but I'll carry on looking none the less.

Comment: Hi Brian, thanks for your answer. So, only replacing YOUR TEXT... with the link? What am I doing wrong (also tried it with a txt shared via onedrive)? https://plnkr.co/edit/VDDINdNoFUwDljbL5S8g?p=info